# Django loops infinitly after startapp method call

Tags: python, django, cs50

I'm doing the `CS50Web` course, and there is a `Django project` in which I want to create a new app called "wikipedia". The problem is that after I run this command in `Windows PowerShell`:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

this loop happens:

[loop print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSRpI.png)

I don't know what I did wrong for that to happen. After running

```
python manage.py startapp wikipedia
```

, I:

1. went to my `Django project` and added 'wikipedia' in the installed apps in `settings.py`
2. went to `urls.py` and added a path like this:

   ```
    path("wiki/", include("wikipedia.urls))
   ```

And then I tried running the server. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show your `wikipedia.urls` code? You might have caused some sort of circular behavior. If you added this code in `wikipedia/urls.py` then that would cause a circular import (the module tries to import itself, which causes it to try to import itself... forever)

Comment: I manage to fix it already, thanks man. I just reinstalled django and it somehow worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have something improperly configured.
Run this:

```
$ pip uninstall django
$ pip install django
$ django-admin startproject <projectname>
$ cd <projectname>
$ django-admin startapp wikipedia
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

do what you described in your question
Also, it is always a better idea to run these things in the CMD, rather than in the PowerShell

Comment: I did what you told but django-admin isn't allowed. It only works if instead of django-admin I use python

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have `url` mappings in your `wikipedia` app `urls.py`? Not having any patterns there could be the cause of an error.

Comment: I have this in the url.py: urlpatterns = [
    path(" ", views.index, name="index"),
    path('wiki/', include("wikipedia.urls"))
]

Comment: I meant your `wikipedia` app `urls.py`, not your root `urls.py`

Comment: that was the wikipedia app urls.py

Comment: Why are you including your apps `urls` within itself? :) Remove the second `path`, the one with the `wiki/` route

Comment: also dont forget to include it in your main project directory `urls.py`